# Active Record Join statement optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, activerecord, orm, redmine

I have found this query (Generated by Redmine 3.4, and Rails 4.2.5.1 - Active Record) by clicking summary on issues sidebar, consuming 100% CPU for more then 3 hours...

Once running `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` on mysql I got this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `custom_values` INNER JOIN issues 
ON issues.id = custom_values.customized_id INNER JOIN issue_statuses 
ON issues.status_id=issue_statuses.id WHERE `custom_values`.`custom_field_id` 
= 16 AND ((issues.id=29951 OR issues.id=29950 OR ........................
```

**Now there goes 29940 OR's!!!** And the rest of SQL query

```
.............OR issues.id=6)) AND `custom_values`.`value` = 'Some Value' 
AND `issue_statuses`.`is_closed` = 1
```

I am wondering if there is a way to optimize above query, so that I can suggest improvement of Redmine or Active Record which caused it.

Comment: I have not found any code location in the reports controller where it would load custom values of the issues. Is it possible you are using some plugin which extends this (and is not well implemented)?

Comment: It might be coming from this plugin: http://redmine.forkbrain.com/

Comment: @HolgerJust  I can provide you with code if you want to dig deeper... SSH test instance...

Comment: Since this doesn't appear to be an entirely open source plugin (which also doesn't appear to be actively maintained judging from their website), I'm not sure if its worthwhile to fix this. In any case, you might want to contact the plugin's authors first.

Comment: For now I'll remove the plugin, and I've submitted feature request http://www.redmine.org/issues/32042 if I catch time, maybe I'll dig into plugin's code or write a patch for custom field and summary based on plugin's code...

Answer (score 1):

How about using `IN`?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `custom_values` INNER JOIN issues 
ON issues.id = custom_values.customized_id INNER JOIN issue_statuses 
ON issues.status_id=issue_statuses.id WHERE `custom_values`.`custom_field_id` 
= 16 AND ((issues.id in (29951, 29950, 29440,.. ........................
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `custom_values` INNER JOIN issues 
ON issues.id = custom_values.customized_id INNER JOIN issue_statuses 
ON issues.status_id=issue_statuses.id WHERE `custom_values`.`custom_field_id` 
= 16 AND ((issues.id between 29951 and 29940...
```

or

by using cte.

```
with cte as (
   select 29940 as ct, 0 as cnt
   union all
   select cte.ct + 1, 1 as cnt 
    from `custom_values`
    inner join issues ON issues.id = custom_values.customized_id 
    inner join issue_statuses ON issues.status_id=issue_statuses.id 
     cte on cte.ct = t.order_sp
    where cte.ct <= 29951  and `custom_values`.`custom_field_id` and issues.id = cte.ct
)select sum(cnt) from cte;
```

Comment: It's a first thing that came to my mind, but to be honest I need to create a dump and import that sql on some server where I can freely test, not to cap the CPU to 100% on production server...

Comment: how about BETWEEN()?

Comment: can't use between, those or's are related just to that project, so it's not sequential).

Comment: No counters, only "in", and it's significantly faster! The first query took 26 seconds on test machine, and with in it took 154ms